# Qual a origem do uso do verbo “ser” para enfatizar que alguma coisa foi feita ao invés de outra coisa?

Tags: verbos, coloquialismos

Por exemplo, na seguinte frase:

*Aquele dia na sua casa foi tão bom e nem percebi, fiquei **foi** preocupando-me com o dia seguinte.*

O verbo *ser* (em negrito) deixa subtendido que o locutor não deveria estar se preocupando com o dia seguinte, mas fazendo alguma outra coisa (no caso, aproveitando o momento bom), mas ao invés, preferiu se preocupar. Outro exemplo claro é quando algo fora do comum está acontecendo, fazendo juntar uma multidão para assistir (como uma briga de rua, por exemplo) e alguém diz:
*eu vou **é** para casa.*

Fica claro que o que essa pessoa quer dizer é: *eu vou para casa ao invés de ficar assistindo essa confusão.* O verbo *ser* deixa implícita essa idéia.

Não sei se esse fenômeno é algo somente da região onde eu moro, mas acredito que é próprio da linguagem coloquial.

Qual a origem desse uso do verbo *ser* e qual é exatamente o valor sintático ou semântico dele nesses casos?

Comment: Não deve ser coisa regional: também se usa muito aqui em Portugal. *Vou é para casa; quero é que não me chateiem; ele é é parvo; não vi a Maria, vi foi a Ana*. Às vezes pode-se acrescentar um *mas*: *vou é para casa = vou mas é para casa*.

Comment: Isto é pura especulação, mas este uso pode ter origem na degradação dum sujeito oracional: *(o que) ele é é parvo; (o que) eu quero é papas e descanso; (quem) eu vi foi a Ana*.

Comment: fiquei **ou** foi preocupando-me??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Essas estruturas chamam-se **clivadas de SER**, e alguns linguistas sugerem “que elas são [pseudoclivadas] reduzidas, resultado do apagamento de certos elementos” (Anderléia Longhin¹, 1999, p. 108), como eu ilustro com estes exemplos da *Gramática do Português* da Gulbenkian² (pp. 2620, 2656 e 2652):

> **Pseudoclivada**                                  →            **Clivada de SER**
>
> **quem** eu vi sair **foi** *o João*                                 →   eu vi sair **foi** *o João*
>
> **o que** o meu pai me ofereceu **foi** *este relógio*  →   o meu pai ofereceu-me **foi** *este relógio*
>
> **do que** eu não gosto **é** *deste tipo de*                →   eu não gosto **é** *deste tipo de comentários*
>                                                 *comentários*

Isto faz sentido também diacronicamente: as pseudoclivadas já vêm do século XIII, enquanto as clivadas SER só encontrei a partir de 1890 (Longhin só as encontrou a partir de 1925, mas em 1999 ela não tinha o Google Books):

> E **o que** quero **é** *dizer loor da Virgem* ([*loor*](http://glossa.gal/glosario/termo/1933) = *louvor*)
> [*Cantigas de Santa Maria*, século XIII](https://books.google.pt/books?id=9M44AQAAMAAJ&pg=RA1-PP1&dq=%22quero%20%C3%A9%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiRwZKglof3AhVJRBoKHRvWBl4Q6AF6BAgDEAI#v=onepage&q=%22quero%20%C3%A9%22&f=false)
>
> Queremos **é** *saber a opinião da commissão*…
> [*Annaes do Congresso Constituinte do Estado do Rio Grande do Sul*, Porto Alegre, 1891](https://books.google.pt/books?id=EdFOAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA39&dq=%22Queremos%20%C3%A9%20saber%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjVzJuoo4f3AhXIQEEAHe4ACigQ6AF6BAgHEAI#v=onepage&q=%22Queremos%20%C3%A9%20saber%22&f=false)
>
> ― Eu quero lá ver isso! respondeu o morgado, cheio de espanto pela extranha lembrança do advogado, você está doido!... Eu quero **é** *que você metta o codigo no… no lume*.
> [João Salgado, *Os Silverios*, Recife, 1895](https://books.google.pt/books?id=isTuAAAAMAAJ&pg=RA1-PA87&dq=%22quero%20%C3%A9%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwie-f-JmIf3AhWlx4UKHYOKCOk4MhDoAXoECAsQAg#v=onepage&q=%22quero%20%C3%A9%22&f=false)

A *Gramática do Português* (p. 2653) observa no entanto que as pseudoclivadas e as clivadas SER diferem nalgumas propriedades sintáticas. Por exemplo, as clivadas SER podem focalizar componentes dum sintagma nominal, enquanto as pseudoclivadas não:

> [Gramatical:] Quero comprar um livro **é** *do Mia Couto*
>
> [Agramatical:] ***De quem** quero comprar um livro **é** *do Mia Couto*

As pseudoclivadas têm mais limitações na clivagem de certas palavras negativas. Por exemplo, em resposta a *não veio muita gente*:

> [Gramatical:] Não veio **foi** *ninguém*
>
> [Agramatical:] ***Quem** não veio **foi** *ninguém*

Nas pseudoclivadas, ao contrário das clivadas de SER, o verbo ser pode ocorrer integrado numa perífrase verbal:

> [Agramatical:] *O Pedro perdeu **pode ter sido** *o passaporte*
>
> [Gramatical:] **O que** o Pedro perdeu **pode ter sido** *o passaporte*

Longhin (p. 186) nota também que as clivadas de SER, ao contrário das pseudoclivadas, têm limitações na clivagem do sujeito. Funcionam com verbos intransitivos (*desapareceram **foi** as joias; amanhã chega **é** o Pedro*), mas não quando há complementos:

> [Duvidoso:] ??Viu o João sair **foi** *a Ana*
>
> [Gramatical:] **Quem** viu o João sair **foi** *a Ana*

Do ponto de vista semântico e pragmático, a pergunta já avança a resposta: a função do verbo ser é pôr em foco o elemento seguinte. Retomando o meu primeiro exemplo:

> Eu vi sair **foi** *o João*

O ***foi*** põe *o João* em foco, negando possíveis alternativas: vi sair o João, não vi sair mais ninguém. A *Gramática do Português* (p. 1628) chama a isto ***foco contrastivo***:

> Do ponto de vista semântico e pragmático, o foco contrastivo introduz um valor de oposição relativamente a uma asserção, a uma pressuposição ou a uma expectativa, explícita ou implicitamente presentes no domínio discursivo. A propriedade central de um foco contrativo é a de adicionar ao valor denotativo básico da frase a expressão da atitude (discordante) relativamente ao que sabe ou supõe serem as expectativas ou convicções do ouvinte.

Referências:
¹ Longhin, Sanderléia Roberta, 1999. *As construções clivadas: uma abordagem diacrônica*, Dissertação, Universidade Estadial de Campinas.
² *Gramática do Português* da Gulbênkian, Vol. III, Lisboa, 2021.

Comment: Óima resposta Jacinto! Eu não sabia que «De quem quero comprar um livro é do Mia Couto» e «Quem não veio foi ninguém». De «O Pedro perdeu pode ter sido o passaporte» e «Viu o João sair foi a Ana», na minha experiência, elas acontecem na fala quando se cortam palavras.

Comment: @Schilive, não sabias que... o quê? O que eu digo, e a Gramática do Português, é que essas construções são agramaticais. Pois, também acho que se ouvem coisas do tipo dos outros dois exemplos: às vezes as pessoas pensam uma coisa, *o Pedro perdeu foi o passaporte*, começam a dizer mas a meio caminho descobrem que não têm a certeza e dizem *pode ter sido*, e sai aquela coisa. Mas se pensassem *poder ter sido* de início provavelmente começariam com *O que o Pedro perdeu*...

Comment: Adoro quando eu faço uma pergunta e o cara responde logo com um textão, já sei que vou aprender algo de fato; Jacinto nunca decepciona. Valeu cara, tu é brabo!

Comment: @єυlєтяicσ, obrigado pá, até me começa melhor o dia!